# Where did a StackSets-created CloudFormation stack originate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In a corporate environment, my AWS account is part of a larger AWS organization.  There are times when a CloudFormation stack will just show up in my account, and it is clear from the name that the stack came from a StackSet that exists in some other corporate oversight account in the organization.  Is there a way to get the account ID of the account that contains the originating StackSet that deployed to my account from just the data in my account?

For example, I noticed that a stack named `StackSet-Custom-CoE-Scanning-CodeAgent-b4707a5d-fa91-4aab-8a4f-41cc6014385d` appeared in my account.  Can I find out where that came from somehow from within my account?  The CloudFormation template description doesn't tell me that, and I don't see any details in the resources or parameters.  How can I tell where this stack came from?

Answer (score 0):

I found one piece of into that *may* yield this--the CloudTrail logs show some details.  Assuming these logs are still available/present, one might look at the event named "CreateStack" that is logged (or potentially others like UpdateStack).  The event shows a principalId, but that Id is just an access key and doesn't allow me to know which account was used.  However, in the requestParameters section, there is a templateURL property that has a value such as

https://executor-templates-173613024251-us-west-1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/0fe18980-4bc0-4823-bda3-8ca0d3fece1b.747943736017.template?versionId=...

That number just before the ".template" seems to be the account ID for the CloudFormation *template*--or "747943736017" in this case.  It doesn't necessarily mean it is the account of the *StackSet*, but it is at least a clue and there's a decent chance the template resides in the same account as the StackSet.